# How can I tell if httponly is set in my application

Tags: .net, httponly

Without looking over the shoulder of a developer, how can I tell if HTTPonly is set properly from the front end of my web application?

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way, I've found so far is to use the [Watcher extension](http://websecuritytool.codeplex.com/) for [Fiddler 2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), as you browse through various sections of your site.

Keep in mind that Watcher is a passive tool - it does not generate any requests against the web/application server. In order to use Watcher effectively, you should atleast execute the bare minimum of test cases in your application, especially in those areas where cookies are created.